# Firebase signInWithRedirect, how to detect a redirect properly?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-authentication

My sign in page currently has the code below. I can successfully use Google sign in, but when it returns to my sign in page before moving to the dashboard, there's a few seconds (or more on slow connections) before it moves to the dashboard. I want to add an indication that it's loading but i can't figure out how to check if the user is arriving at the sign in page from the Google sign in redirect. What would be best practice for this? I tried making an intermediate page using router.push which does the handleRegister on that page instead (and therefore the user gets redirected back to that page when logging in) but it keeps triggering the handleRegister and going back to the google sign in page again. Losing my mind here, what am i missing?

```
useEffect(() => {
        const redirectResult = async () => {
            try {
                const result = await getRedirectResult(auth)
                    .then(async (result) => {
                        console.log("redirect result:", result);

                        if (result) {
                            // @ts-ignore
                            const isNewUser = result?._tokenResponse?.isNewUser;

                            if (isNewUser) {
                                console.log("new user");
                            } else {
                                console.log("user already exists");
                            }

                            router.push("/dashboard");
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log("error:", error);
                        // Handle Errors here.
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error); // Debug errors from redirect response
            }
        };

        redirectResult();
    }, []);

    const handleRegister = async () => {
        try {
            await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```